# Postfix as a relay for specific networks only

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix, smtp

I have a strange issue with postfix that is driving me a little up the wall as it seems to work 50% of the time but with no changes made.

What I want to achieve:

I have a number of virtual servers on a few different external networks e.g.
1.2.3.4/24
10.20.30.40/24
11.22.33.44/24

I have set up 4 postfix servers with round robin dns, they all have the same main.cf config file.

I want only servers in those external subnets to be allowed to relay through the mail servers, no username or password required.

I did some reading and it seemed that the mynetworks option was the way to go however it only seems to work 50% of the time, even if I take the other 3 servers out of the picture and leave 1 mail server running 50% of the time I get relay denied errors.

here is the config in use:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = relay.example.co.uk
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = relay.example.co.uk, localhost.example.co.uk, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks = 1.2.3.4/24
mynetworks = 10.20.30.40/24
mynetworks = 11.22.33.44/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 2s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```

I suspect that the mydestination may have a part to play here but any help is welcome?

Comment: update: I may have actually answered my own question:

It seems it is not correct to stack the mynetworks, instead they should be entered as: mynetworks - 1.1.1.1/24 2.2.2.2/24 on a single line.

Testing this now, all looks good so far, happy to hear any other comments though regarding cleaning up the config etc.

Comment: You are running *4* postfix servers with the same A record **WHY**, exactly ? This appears to me the root of the issue. Well, that, and the fact that you're not using submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to postconf(5) man page:

> When the same parameter is defined multiple times, only the last instance is remembered.

This means that the definition of your `mynetworks` variable should look something like this:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 1.2.3.4/24 10.20.30.40/24      11.22.33.44/24
```

or

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
 1.2.3.4/24
 10.20.30.40/24
 11.22.33.44/24
```

or

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104, [::1]/128,
 1.2.3.4/24,
 10.20.30.40/24,
 11.22.33.44/24,
```

Comment: which would explain why it was working some of the time.

Comment: Actually since setting the config again like that all I get are timeouts now, I can telnet to port 25 but when sending mail nothing happens:

Oct 15 11:53:55 relay postfix/master[889]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling

Comment: what about `mydestination = relay.example.co.uk, localhost.example.co.uk, , localhost` ? There is an extra ` ,` before localhost. Also, make sure if you use one IP/network block per line, either put one or more sapce/tabs before (this tells postfix that this line continues the previous one)